# Filter to remove image dimension attributes?

Tags: images, filters, post-thumbnails

I'm working on a site based on a fluid width css template which sets a max-width on images to the width of the column containing them, and I need to remove the inline **width** and **height** dimension attributes that WordPress adds to images.

I'm doing it with my featured images with this filter:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10, 3 );

function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

I know I can apply the same filter to **the_content**, if necessary. But is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: First off, thanks for the very helpful code. It works perfectly to strip width and height attributes from the img tag, but for some reason it also seem to strip the caption shortcode if there is one. Does anyone know why this is and how to correct it?

Comment: Maybe you should post this as its own question? It seems sufficiently distinct enough from mine that it deserves its own response. Nevertheless, I'll try and answer... for anyone else finding this answer and having the same problem:

Your problem is that the function `img_caption_shortcode`, which processes the caption shortcode, requires that a width be specified in the caption shortcode attributes. Otherwise, it skips the caption altogether and just returns the content wrapped inside the `[caption]` shortcode tags.

Comment: If you want to be able to use caption shortcodes without a defined width, you will have to define your caption markup in a function that's hooked on the filter `img_caption_shortcode`. Writing up the code for a function like that is more than I can fit into comments here, though.

Comment: @goldenapples, thanks for your helpful reply. I have done as you suggested and asked a new question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32931/removing-image-and-caption-dimension-attributes. Any input on that would be greatly appreciated. As I explain in the question, I'm not sure the filter on `img_caption_shortcode` will be enough the solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the bigger picture of what you're trying to do without seeing your actual content, but can't this be remedied using CSS alone?  If you're using a max-width on your images you should be able to conquer the height problem by adding a height: auto; to your content images.

Comment: @binaryorganic - Yes, now I realize that it can be... at least in any browser I'd be concerned with, css width and height properties should override inline `width` attributes. When I was originally working on this, there were issues in older versions of IE with this functionality, though I don't remember what exactly they were. And regardless, it seemed better not to be outputting a lot of extra dimensional properties and having to override them.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Thanks all!

The **image_send_to_editor** filter was the one I was looking for... thanks @t31os for pointing it out.

Here's my functions now.

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );

function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

This removes inline dimension attributes from images retrieved with `the_post_thumbnail()`, and prevents those attributes from being added to new images added to the editor. Doesn't remove them from images retrieved through `wp_get_attachment_image` or other related functions (no hooks in there), but those cases can be processed in the templates files when necessary.

Comment: I had to remove the \s from the regex. After that, it worked fine. I think it was because I did not have a trailing space after the last doublequote on the height setting.

Comment: @MattSlay Is it just me that has a problem with permanently modifying the content of the site? A responsive theme shouldn't have to modify the content of the website to get it to format correctly. I vote to remove the filter from `image_send_to_editor` and instead add it to `the_content` - like this [blog post](http://speakinginbytes.com/2012/11/responsive-images-in-wordpress/). This separates presentation logic from the content.

Comment: @BFTrick - Seems like a matter of context to me. For a responsive theme, I'd agree with you because you can't depend on existing content having been processed in this way, and you don't know if the next theme installed will need those dimension attributes.  
  
In my case, I was building an app where the theme was integral to the content, so I chose the less processor-intensive method of processing the images when they were first added. But you do make a good point.

Comment: Warning: This answer breaks image captions in WordPress 3.5.1.

Answer (score 5):

Modified this script a bit. Thanks for the help!

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
// Genesis framework only
add_filter( 'genesis_get_image', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
// Removes attached image sizes as well
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Careful, though. Filtering the_content will also filter youtube videos and any other width/height attribute.

Comment: True, but that may be a good thing in a responsive site. If one needs to do it for images then one probably also needs to do it for other media.

Answer (score 1):

if you set image size in function.php as a "gallery"

```
add_image_size( 'gallery', 200, 120, true );
```

you can remove width and height of specific image size such as "gallery":

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10, 4 );

function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id,$post_thumbnail) {
    if ($post_thumbnail=='gallery'){
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying that filter to `the_content` will fire it for all content.  This will be effective, but could affect the performance and load time of your site.  It would be better if you tell WordPress to just not insert the inline width and height tags when you insert images in the first place.

Unfortunately, the scripts that actually insert the image are built in JavaScript and interact with the TinyMCE wysiwyg editor.  There might be a way to hook into it directly, but not using the standard `add_filter()` calls.

Comment: Wouldn't a filter on `image_send_to_editor` work here?

Comment: @t31os - I think that's what I was looking for! Don't know why I didn't see that hook before.

Comment: Well i certainly hope it helps, it looks like it might do the trick...report back and let us know. :)

Comment: @t31os Yup, that did the trick! Thanks! I'll post it as an answer, unless you get to it first.

Comment: You go for it mate, i'm not too fussed, happy you were able to find a solution... ;)