# How do you remove hard coded thumbnail image dimensions?

Tags: post-thumbnails

How can I remove the width and height attributes from the post_thumbnail when inserting with `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`?

```
<img width="800" height="533" src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/image.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" />
```

Comment: look for thumbnail.php file, not sure but usually that files contain the hard coding

Comment: In case you were wondering, I want to be able to modify widths and height with CSS - more specifically set a max-width and let the height set itself rather than default to the hard coded one.

Comment: use firebug to get the exact class or ID, or give me your URL

Comment: Changing anything in a file outside the theme (for example post-thumbnail-template.php) would be a bad idea as any WordPress update would overwrite it.

Comment: What makes you think you need to remove the attributes to do what you want?

Comment: Look at my comment above..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Related: [Filter to remove image dimension attributes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/filter-to-remove-image-dimension-attributes)

There's a filter on `post_thumbnail_html` which receives as its argument the full html element representing the post thumbnail image before it's echoed to the page. You can filter out the dimensions with a bit of regex:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10, 3 );

function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me. add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10, 3 );

function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {
 if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
  $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
 }    
    return $html;
}

Comment: This will remove width/height from all instances of where `the_post_thumbnail()` is used.

Answer (score 6):

you could just grab the url of the thumb and put it in an img tag yourself:

```
<?php
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'your_thumb_handle' );
?>
<img src="<?php echo $thumbnail['0']; ?>" />
```

Comment: That's the only solution I've come across too, was just hoping there was a way to do it without a workaround.

Comment: But you also need to query for the alt and title attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

this will do the job, "the_contnet" will remove all post content text image width and height.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: For me, this also strips the containing 'figure' tag, and removes the caption. :/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this solution below as I'm not doing a global replace with a function. This would be incorporated into your theme files.

```
<?php echo preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"/', '', get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'large' ) ); ?>
```

You can replace "large" with "thumbnail", "medium", "full", or your custom image size declared in your theme.