# How to remove attachments size attribute

Tags: attachments, images, filters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent Width and Height Attributes in Image Tag Output](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53524/prevent-width-and-height-attributes-in-image-tag-output)

i would like to remove the width="512" height="128" attributes on an attachments

this method is fine on images displayed in the_content : 
[Filter to remove image dimension attributes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/filter-to-remove-image-dimension-attributes)

but i can't find a way to make it work on an attachement i call outside of the_content with wp_get_attachment_image.

how can i do this ?

Comment: just found the solution !

$myimage = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", wp_get_attachment_image($first_attachment->ID, full) );
echo $myimage;

Answer (score 1):

`wp_get_attachment_image()` does not pass output through any filters. You should apply changes to output of this function or use custom function for output.

Comment: There's a filter inside `wp_get_attachment_image` though, named .. `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`, perhaps you could catch the size there? Not sure who downvoted this answer, curious to know the reasoning..

Comment: @Mark  filtered attributes are additional ones, width and height are retrieved and concatenated separately and do not pass through that filter.