# Prevent Width and Height Attributes in Image Tag Output

Tags: images

I'm trying to control the output of the random image within this bit of code. The end goal is to NOT output the `width` and `height` attributes for the image.

I want this:

```
<img src="URL HERE" alt="ALT HERE"/>
```

BUT I DON'T WANT THIS (which is what the code below currently outputs):

```
<img src="URL HERE" alt="ALT HERE" width="200px" height="200px" />
```

**My code:**

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());

$args = array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status' => null,
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'exclude' => $thumb_id
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'full', false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) and build a simplified `img` element. You may use something like the following code as a replacement for `wp_get_attachment_image()`:

```
function wpse_53524_get_image_tag( $attach_id, $size, $icon, $alt = '' )
{
    if ( $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attach_id, $size, $icon ) )
    {
        return "<img src='{$src[0]}' alt='$alt' />";
    }

}
```

Put the function above into your theme's `functions.php`. Call it like `wp_get_attachment_image()`:

```
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    echo wpse_53524_get_image_tag( $attachment->ID, 'full', false );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I've got it working now. Thanks. I can be a bit of a fruitbar when it comes to PHP. Out of curiosity, do PHP functions always have to appear in the functions.php file?

Comment: They may be placed almost anywhere. A central place is just easier to work with.