# Removing Image and Caption Dimension Attributes

Tags: filters, images

This question is an offshoot from the [this discussion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/filter-to-remove-image-dimension-attributes) on removing dimension attributes from images. The solution code provided on that thread works very well except that it has the unfortunate side effect that any `[caption]` shortcodes are striped from the image.

After several hours of digging through the core code, I found the cause of this. The wpeditimage TinyMCE plugin that's responsible for adding the `[caption]` shortcode checks for width attributes in the shortcode and the `img` tag. If it doesn't find them, it simply remove the caption. Since, this is done 'on the fly' with javascript in the TinyMCE editor, I can't think of any type of WordPress filter that would address this issue. I would be very happy to be proven wrong however. :)

As a final note, my temporary solution has been to use the following jQuery to strip all of the offending tags client side. This, in conjunction with a filter on `img_caption_shortcode` to prevent a width style from being used there, seems to do the job. It's not pretty, but it's a band-aid for now. Anyone have a better idea?

```
// Strip width and height attributes from img, video, and object in the main article so we can have fluid images
var $fluid_items = $('.main-article-wrapper').find('img,video,object');
$fluid_items.removeAttr('width');
$fluid_items.removeAttr('height');
```

Comment: Hmmm... is being able to use the visual editor a requirement? If you only use the HTML editor, a filter on __img_caption_shortcode__ works fine...

Comment: @goldenapples, yeah, I don't want to loose the visual editor as I am going to be having non-technical people edit the site. Thanks for the suggestion though. Any other ideas?

Comment: Dominic, can you provide the code for "a filter on img_caption_shortcode to prevent a width style from being used there"? This is exactly what I need, but I don't know how to write that filter.

Comment: @Wendy, hmm, I can't paste the whole thing in a comment. If you want to ask another question and give me a link to it, I'll post it as answer.

Comment: In case you didn't want to go through all of that, I basically just modified the [Codex example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter#Example).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

it might not be the exact answer you're after but i think i just found a pretty good workaround.

Iv'e taken the following code from the twenty-eleven theme CSS (who's neatly responsive imho):

```
/* Images */
.entry-content img,
.comment-content img,
.widget img {
    max-width: 97.5%; /* Fluid images for posts, comments, and widgets */
}
img[class*="align"],
img[class*="wp-image-"] {
    height: auto; /* Make sure images with WordPress-added height and width >attributes are scaled correctly */
}
img.size-full {
    max-width: 97.5%;
    width: auto; /* Prevent stretching of full-size images with height and >>width attributes in IE8 */
}
```

This was enuff to make all the images responsive (at least those embedded in the content...)
Now i have responsive images, but when caption is used i still have the same problem, that occurs because the tinyMCE adds a style attribute to the caption container with the image's width. 
To fix that all i had to do is add this to my CSS:

```
            .wp-caption { max-width: 100%; }
```

Done! works fine for me, although it might not work for featured images.

I hope this helps someone :-)

Comment: I haven't had the time to test this fully yet, but it's already proved quite useful in other areas. Thanks for the help.

Comment: my pleasure :-)

Comment: Tested it in IE9, doesnt seem to work as intended!

Comment: This conflicts with the old IE browsers

Comment: really great solution! thx

Comment: This got me where I needed, although I just used width: auto and height: auto.