# Remove width and height attributes from [gallery] output

Tags: shortcode, gallery, customization

WordPress automatically adds the width and height attributes to [gallery] shortcode images.

How to delete these attributes? Something [like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/filter-to-remove-image-dimension-attributes) but for [gallery] output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a couple of options:

1. Create a new shortcode, e.g. my_gallery. You can copy the code in
   `wp-includes/media.php`. Look for the code staring with
   `add_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');` and then the actual
   function. Rename / modify as needed. The actual img link is within
   the `$link` variable
2. Use something like this (untested), which should work but might
   strip-out **all** width/height from any link.

_

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'remove_img_width_height', 10, 1);

function remove_img_width_height($html) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: @TohidGolkar has the right idea below. Both of the options provided are terrible. Rewriting the core (1st solution), and removing widths/heights across all attachment links is no better.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to *rewrite* the core, but just to adapt it (copy the code and re-use it as you see fit) and create your own version of it. As for the 2nd option - yeah, it's not great and I explained how it might alter all image links. I totally agree that the version of @TohidGolkar looks much better since it's more fine-grained.

Answer (score 5):

if you set image size in function.php as a "gallery"

```
add_image_size( 'gallery', 200, 120, true );
```

you can remove width and height of specific image size such as "gallery":

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'remove_img_width_height', 10, 4);

function remove_img_width_height( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id,$post_thumbnail) {
    if ($post_thumbnail=='gallery'){
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: looks much better than my 2nd snippet / suggestion. +1